# Should I edit a title when unnecessary phrases are used like "what should I do?"

Tags: discussion, edits, asking-questions, title

Today I reviewed a question and saw the phrase "What should I do?" at the end of the question. The edit was rejected.

The SO article https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit says:

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better [...]

I feel this is an unnecessary phrase and should not belong to the title because it doesn't describe in any way what the user wants to know, and makes the question longer and less attractive.

It doesn't feel correct for me to hit the *No action need* button.

So should I avoid title edits like this?

Comment: I'd have rejected too, there were grammar mistakes on the title that you didn't fix: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5405502

Comment: thanks for your comment, yeah i really didn't notice this on my edit. i don't linked to the question because i know that this reject might have serious reasons why. i created this question on meta because i feel confused how i handle further edits that may have pharses in the title and avoid "minor edits" so in this example - should i have simple hit the _i'm done_ button? (if only the title phrase was "wrong")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm one of the folks that think *any* edit that actually fixes something is a good one, and we should be thankful for it. That's a nice premise to hold, a delightful ideal, but breaks down ... a bit, in practical application.

While your edits create work for *other people*, try to suggest edits that produce a net gain that is better than or equal to the value of the time it takes to review. Put simply, try to find posts where you can make a more *substantive* difference, and save the very minor edits for when you can edit directly.

Then, when you *can* edit directly, just be conscious that every edit also creates an inbox notification, which typically summons the author back to the post. Write clear, descriptive edit summaries so folks know exactly what you changed and why. Be respectful of their wishes, as the author of the post.

All in all, it's just optimizing for other people's time, either way you look at it.

Comment: thanks for this nice and clear answer i was looking for! @Tim Post so when review posts and see a minor edit, is it ok to hit _No Action need_ ?

Comment: @ins0 It's hard to give a blanket answer to that. Does that edit _really_ fix the only thing wrong with the post? Did they leave a lot of other stuff that should have been fixed? Is the edit so trivial just to add `inline code`? The reason we have humans review is we need powers of reasoning and such, so context is really king. I think it boils down to - _was the 30 seconds I spent on this wisely spent or taken from something else that could have used it more?_ But even then, there's no _single_ test to decide what action you should take. Just use your best judgement.

Comment: ok thanks i will keep all that in mind on my next reviews, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

That edit may have mildly improved things, but further down that article you linked to it also states:

> *Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.*

It's debatable if the post was *substantively* improved by that edit. It is possibly better in future to edit the title *and* improve the content of the question at the same time. This could be; tagging, spelling, formatting, improving general clarity.

Not that you were *wrong* to suggest the edit, and not that people who rejected it were wrong either. But the more substantial the edits you suggest, the greater the likelyhood of them being accepted (as long as you don't actually change the overall topic of the question, of course!).

Comment: as i hit save the post was edited by a different user so only  the title was the last that feels "wrong" and changes in title don't feel for me a "minor edit"

Comment: @ins, note that at least 3 people need to review your suggested edit. So, you're reviewing that post, and then 3 others need to review it too because you made a trivial edit. I don't agree with JonW here; to me, that's a huge waste of time.

Comment: @Arjan it sounds like you *do* agree with me actually. I'm suggesting that he make a more substantial edit instead of just editing that title if he doesn't want his edit to fall approval.

Comment: True, I mostly agree, except for *"Not that you were wrong to suggest the edit"*... Heck, +1 ;-) (And, @ins, it's not *very* bad what you did; it's just that some, including me, find it a waste of time. That's why I don't review suggested edits. Others might review, but reject.)

Comment: ok thanks guys idk as said - so in this case (edits on post was made before i could hit the submit button) you just leave the post "deal with it" because of "trivial title changes" and hit the _I'm done_ button? :D it feels wrong because improvement on titles should not count as "minor" edit